# laravel generate compact data depends from statement

Tags: laravel

How to genereate comapct viev in laravel?

for example we have a view with

```
compact('title', 'settings','users','items')
```

compact will pass data if it is set

but will throw error if data is not set.

How to add data to compact after

```
if(isset())??
```

so for example

```
if(isset($title)){
//some code
}
compact(some data passed by statements)
```

i do not want array solution like push and pass array to compact like:

```
compact('array')
```

have to be like that

```
compact('title','items')
//or
compact('title', 'users','items')
```

there is possible to do that? or i have to check data inside blade?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? This is causing multiple problems in your view, cause you have to check wether the variable ist set or not...

Comment: Just an idea: initialize variable with null or an empty laravel collection...

Comment: yes i have to check json value that contain lots of data and pass selected data without errors , sometimes some object or array inside object might be invalid so i will have to throw error but output also

Comment: @jtwes is right, you can initialize all variable to a default value, I add that compact() raise a E_NOTICE level error in case of unset variables.

Comment: ye that might work.

Comment: From where does `$title` come? If it is a method argument, you can set the default value to `null` or `false` directly there. Otherwise I can't assume a case where the variables would not be set in the situation you explained.